# Why does my Laravel app output html tags as string

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and trying to replicate the code from this site: [Create your first laravel app](https://auth0.com/blog/creating-your-first-laravel-app-and-adding-authentication/#Run-Migrations), but the html tags are echoed as string instead of tags.

The site I'm using uses stuff like these:

```php
<span class="nt">&lt;th&gt;</span>
```

and I dont know what it does. For example, the original `@foreach` line was:

```php
@foreach($characters as $key =&lt; $value)
```

and Laravel was interpreting it as

```php
<?php $__currentLoopData = $characters; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $key =&gt; $value): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>`. i had to change =&lt; to => for the code to run..attached below is the welcome.blade.php code and a screenshot 




            @if(Auth::check())
              <span class="c">&lt;!-- Table --&gt;</span>
              <span class="nt">&lt;table</span> <span class="na">class=</span><span class="s">"table"</span><span class="nt">&gt;</span>
                  <span class="nt">&lt;tr&gt;</span>
                      <span class="nt">&lt;th&gt;</span>Character<span class="nt">&lt;/th&gt;</span>
                      <span class="nt">&lt;th&gt;</span>Real Name<span class="nt">&lt;/th&gt;</span>
                  <span class="nt">&lt;/tr&gt;</span>
                  @foreach($characters as $key => $value)
                    <span class="nt">&lt;tr&gt;</span>
                      <span class="nt">&lt;td&gt;</span>{{ $key }}<span class="nt">&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;</span>{{ $value }}<span class="nt">&lt;/td&gt;</span>
                    <span class="nt">&lt;/tr&gt;</span>
                  @endforeach
              <span class="nt">&lt;/table&gt;</span>
            @endif


    <span class="nt">&lt;/div&gt;</span>
    @if(Auth::guest())
      <span class="nt">&lt;a</span> <span class="na">href=</span><span class="s">"/login"</span> <span class="na">class=</span><span class="s">"btn btn-info"</span><span class="nt">&gt;</span> You need to login to see the list &gt;&gt;<span class="nt">&lt;/a&gt;</span>
    @endif
<span class="nt">&lt;/div&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;/div&gt;</span></div>
@endsection.
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That doesn't look right. I'm guessing it's a formatting mistake on the auth0 site.

If you have a look at that view template in the [repo](https://github.com/auth0-blog/laravel-auth0-got/blob/master/resources/views/welcome.blade.php) they provide, it doesn't contain the `&lt` and `&gt`, etc.

The CSS classes such as `"nt"` and `"c"` are classes that are used to do syntax highlighting on the code in the auth0 post. For example, in the screenshot below you'll see where the `"nt"` class was applied to the `span` element in which a `div` tag was displayed in a part of the code that was rendered correctly.

[image: Screenshot of syntax highlighted code on auth0 post]

The `&lt;`'s and `&gt;`'s that you see are there to force the browser to render `<` and `>`, respectively, as text. If instead the characters `<` and `>` were used themselves, the browser would interpret them as html elements.

In this case, however, there seems to have been a formatting mistake on the part of the code that you posted on the auth0 side before they sent back the html to the browser.

Comment: Thank you very much.. So the whole <span class="nt" > is what exactly?.. Just curious